# Session Cache Bug When in @future Context

Tags: future, cache

We built a little framework around managing Session Cache. It wasn't until today we referenced some of the caching methods from a `@future` method. I understand that in this case it might be better to use Platform Cache instead, or don't use cache at all, but that's irrelevant here. What's interesting is that there is `isAvailable()` method which based on the documentation should return `false` in this scenario:

> isAvailable() - Returns true if the session cache is available for use.
>   The session cache isn’t available when an active session isn’t
>   present, such as in asynchronous Apex or code called by asynchronous
>   Apex. For example, if batch Apex causes an Apex trigger to execute,
>   the session cache isn’t available in the trigger because the trigger
>   runs in asynchronous context.

Instead, the code breaks and a system error is thrown:

```
|FATAL_ERROR|cache.Org.OrgCacheException: Failed Cache.Session.getDefault():Session not found - Session Cache not supported

Class.cache.PlatformCacheDelegateWrapper.getSessionDefault: line 16, column 1
Class.cache.Session.getDefault: line 99, column 1
Class.cache.Session.isAvailable: line 91, column 1
Class.CacheManager: line 14, column 1
```

Line 14 in `CacheManager` is:

`if (Cache.Session.isAvailable())`

Anyone else experienced this? Should I file a bug with SFDC or is there something else that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to file a bug; this is something happening within the system code (and it shouldn't be). For now, do not attempt to call the cache methods without first checking for a session:

```
if(UserInfo.getSessionId() != null) {
    // It should be safe to use Cache.Session now.
```